# How to set argparse arguments from python script

Tags: python, argparse, setup.py, entry-point

I have a `main` function specified as entry point in my package's `setup.py` which uses the `argparse` package in order to pass command line arguments (see [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853088/setuptools-not-passing-arguments-for-entry-points)):

```
# file with main routine specified as entry point in setup.py
import argparse
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('a', type=str, help='mandatory argument a')
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

Ideally, I would like to use the same `main` function in the package's tests as suggested [here](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html). In the latter context, I would like to call the `main` function from within the test class and set (some of) the command line arguments prior to the function call (which otherwise will fail, due to missing arguments).

```
# file in the tests folder calling the above main function
class TestConsole(TestCase):
    def test_basic(self):
        set_value_of_a()
        main()
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Why don't you add `kwargs` to `main` and only if they're `None`, you set them to the `parse_args`?

Comment: @William Fernandes Great, Thanks!!!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The **argparse** module actually reads input variables from special variable, which is called **ARGV** (short from **ARG**ument **V**ector). This variable is usually accessed by reading **sys.argv** from **sys** module.

This variable is a ordinary list, so you can append your command-line parameters to it like this:

```
import sys
sys.argv.extend(['-a', SOME_VALUE])
main()
```

However, messing with sys.argv at runtime is not a good way of testing. 
A much more cleaner way to replace the **sys.argv** for some limited scope is using **unittest.mock.patch** context manager, like this:

```
with unittest.mock.patch('sys.argv'. ['-a', SOME_VALUE]):
    main()
```

[Read more about unittest.mock.patch in documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch)

Also, check this SO question:

[How do I set sys.argv so I can unit test it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668947/how-do-i-set-sys-argv-so-i-can-unit-test-it)

Comment: For whatever reason, `from unittest.mock import patch` with `patch(...)` worked, while `import unittest` with `unittest.mock.patch(...)` did not. In any case, this helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

@William Fernandes: Just for the sake of completeness, I'll post the full solution in the way that was suggested by (checking for an empty dict not `kwargs is None`):

```
def main(**kwargs):
    a = None
    if not kwargs:
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('a', type=str, help='mandatory argument a')
        args = parser.parse_args()
        a = args.a
    else:
        a = kwargs.get('a')

    print(a)
```

From within the test class the `main` function can then be called with arguments:

```
# file in the tests folder calling the above main function
class TestConsole(TestCase):
    def test_basic(self):
        main(a=42)
```

The call from the command line without `kwargs` then requires the specification of the command line argument `a=...`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `kwargs` to `main` and if they're `None`, you set them to the `parse_args`.